# What does the top line of the IntelliJ Project Tool Window mean?

Tags: intellij-idea

The IntelliJ Project Tool Window is not so far as I have found well documented.

If my project is named "framework", I often see project [framework (n)] as the top of my source tree. What does the [project (n)] mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name of the project module:

[image: module name]

Comment: Thank you! I could not find that simple fact anywhere in the IntelliJ docs...